# Json cannot add dependencies

Tags: json, spring-boot

Spring Boot version is using version 4.5.2. How can I add Json dependencies to this version?

This error occurs when accessing the current site.

**This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Feb 28 03:31:40 KST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No converter found for return value of type: class com.example.demo.Dto.TestVo
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class com.example.demo.Dto.TestVo
    at**

Source code of `TestVo` class:

```
package com.example.demo.Dto; 

public class TestVo { 
    private int seq; 
    private String title; 
    private String contents; 
    private String author; 
    private String password; 
    private int reads = 0; 
    private String deleted = "N"; 

    @Override 
    public String toString() { 
        return "TestVo [seq=" + seq + ", title=" + title + ", contents=" + contents + ", author=" + author + ", password=" + password + ", reads=" + reads + ", deleted=" + deleted + "]"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add source code of DTO. Not sure if explicitly adding jackson dependencies are required for Spring 4.5.2.

Comment: package com.example.demo.Dto;


 
 public class TestVo {
     private int seq;
     private String title;
     private String contents;
     private String author;
     private String password;
     private int reads = 0;
     private String deleted = "N";
 
     @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "TestVo [seq=" + seq + ", title=" + title + ", contents=" + contents + ", author=" + author
    + ", password=" + password + ", reads=" + reads + ", deleted=" + deleted + "]";
 }
      
 }
 
                           this is dto source code

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, we need to see your dto code, but try and see if adding the following dependency to your pom.xml, solves your problem.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: <version>2.10.2</version> Adding this part will give you a yellow underline

Comment: try these things:
1. change the 2 'int' datatypes to 'Integer'.
2. add default constructor and constructor with arguments.
3. make your class implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
4. Add the jackson core dependencies.

         <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You have not added any getter, and setter methods for member variables for `TestVo` class.

Add getter and setter methods.

Comment: Still no connection.

Comment: So, you are getting the same error after adding getter/setters?